# Search and replace conditionally using regex in VS Code

Tags: regex, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have multiple TypeScript files with this object structure:

```js
const x = {
    abc: {
        foo: {
            bar1: true,
            bar2: false,
            bar3: true,
        },
        bar: {
            baz1: false,
            baz2: false,
            baz3: true,
        }
    }
}
```

> Note: this is the type  `{ abc: { foo: { [P in string]: boolean }, bar: { [P in string]: boolean } } }`

How can I use a regex "find and replace" in VS code to replace all values ONLY inside `foo` object? I want to replace all `true` values inside `foo` with `'supported'` and all the `false` values in the `foo` object with `'not-supportes'`.

Is there a way to find and replace conditionally?
I don't mind replacing all `true` values first and all `false` after, but it has to be only inside `foo`.

I tried a bunch of different regexs but can't figure out how to match all `true|false` values. And even if I can get all of them matched, how do I replace all of the in the replace statement?

Comment: why not just use multi-cursor editing?

Comment: @starball if he has 100+ files it is a lot of work, if it are 2 files he would do it by hand

Comment: yeah. I have 252 objects across 98 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do a regex find for : `(foo: *\{[\n\w: ,'\-]+?)(true)`

replace with: `$1'supported'`

Apply as often till VSC tells you no replacements made.

The same for `false`

do a regex find for : `(foo: *\{[\n\w: ,'\-]+?)(false)`

replace with: `$1'not-supported'`

As often till no replacement made

Comment: So `(foo: *\{[\n\w: ,'\-]+?)(true)` only finds the first value of true. Once I click replace it no longer find the other value and I end up with `foo: { bar1: 'supported', bar2: false, bar3: true, }`

Comment: Actually nevermind. I think it works.

Comment: Actually 1 case it doesn't cover if there is field that is commented out. e.g.
```foo: {
bar1: 'supported',
// bar2: false,
bar3: true, 
}```
it won't pick up `bar3` value

Comment: This seem to work `(foo: *\{[\n/+\w: ,'\-]+?)(true)`

Comment: @Alkasai I can only go by the example case you give me, I can not assume you have some other text in the object and adapt the regex to handle it

Comment: @Alkasai do you also have `+` characters inside the object

Comment: no i do not have `+`'s

Comment: @Alkasai then why have you added it to the regex

Comment: to catch 1 or more `/`s

Comment: inside `[]` `+` has no special meaning

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the "Find in Selection" toggle button of the find widget. First, select the following from the inside of `x.abc.foo`:

```json
            bar1: true,
            bar2: false,
            bar3: true,
```

Then open the find widget with <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, then enable "Find in Selection" by clicking its toggle button, then put `: true` in the search field, then put `: 'supported'` in the replace field, then use the "Replace All" action, then repeat the process for replacing `false` with `'not-supported'`.

I think rioV8's answer works better when you have a lot of files and not many object property values to replace, but mine works better when you have a few files with many object property values to replace, since my solution needs to be repeated for as many files as you want to do this in, but rioV8's solution apparently requires clicking a button as many times as there are property values to replace in the file with the most property values to replace.